# How to safely remove hardware (windows phone 8.1) after testing app in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

How can I safely disconnect my Windows Phone after connecting it to my computer and then testing an app I created on it using Visual Studio?

I post this here because it seems to be more related to the program Visual Studio than to the hardware Windows Phone.

Every time I click "Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media" in the Notification Area, and select my phone, I get a message saying "Problem Ejecting USB Composite Device" - "Windows can't stop your 'Lumia 535 (RM-1089)' device because a program is still using it. Close any programs that might be using the device, and then try again later."

I already closed Visual Studio, every other program, and even restarted the computer (leaving the phone still connected).

Is the only way to turn the computer off and then disconnect the phone?  There has got to be a quicker way to do this.  Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to unplug your phone; no need to eject "safely." I've worked on Windows Phone since the WP7 release, and I have never "safely" removed the phone, nor have I ever seen anyone else "safely" remove their phones. Everyone just pulls the cable.

That said, I did just try and I had no problems ejecting my Lumia 920 so something is causing an issue on your machine - perhaps a virus scanner or some kind of indexing software?

If you really want to be sure, you can try running `net stop ipoverusbsvc` from an elevated command-prompt before you try and eject. Just remember to re-start it (or reboot) before you try and do any VS Debugging. Powering-down the computer is the ultimate work-around if you're still concerned.

Comment: Can you please link to some kind of reference to this?  I searched all over and couldn't find anything concrete referencing my situation.

Comment: I don't know of anything off-hand, but would you accept anecdotal evidence of the people at Microsoft working on the OS doing it all the time?

Comment: Well yeah I guess so.  As long as the phone's not syncing or transferring files, it seems that it should be okay to just disconnect it.  Especially after closing all programs and restarting the computer and I could still not "safely remove hardware", I can not think of a relevant reason that the phone would still be in use by any program.  Maybe just some background task is hooked into the phone and monitoring it.  One thing I know for sure though is that if you want to take the SD card out of the phone, you must surely first safely remove it using the system settings.